# index in array php, date formating

Tags: php, arrays, date, format

Sorry for my English, and i don't know if my question is righ.

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (

        [date] => 2013-01-22
        [id] => 1
        [views] => 33286

    )

   [1] => Array
    (

        [date] => 2013-01-23
        [id] => 1
        [views] => 33223

    )


[2] => Array
    (

        [date] => 2013-01-22
        [id] => 2
        [views] => 33223

    )

 [3] => Array
    (

        [date] => 2013-01-23
        [id] => 2
        [views] => 33223

    )
)
```

As you can see, id 1 & 2 has views in 2 days : 22-01-2013 and 23-01-2013, so my question is how can i print them like this:

```
id     22-01-2013    23-01-2013
1        33286         33223
2        33223         33223
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Basically just use a loop and assign to a multidimensional array with `$out[$date][$id] = $views`. Then it gets easier to print such a table.

Comment: i think you getting this from mysql so if yes then can u post query please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt your end goal is to write out a table of values.  But in case it is, here's some code that would do that.

```
<?php

$a = array(
    array('date'=>'2013-01-22', 'id'=>1, 'views'=>33286),
    array('date'=>'2013-01-23', 'id'=>1, 'views'=>33223),
    array('date'=>'2013-01-22', 'id'=>2, 'views'=>33223),
    array('date'=>'2013-01-23', 'id'=>2, 'views'=>33223),
);

$table = array();
$cols = array();
foreach ($a as $item)
{
   $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($item['date']));
   $table[$item['id']][$date] = $item['views'];
   $cols[$date] = 1;
}
$cols = array_keys($cols);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo("id\t" . implode("\t", $cols) . "\r");
foreach ($table as $rowName=>$row)
{
   echo("$rowName\t");
   foreach ($cols as $colName)
   {
      echo(@$row[$colName] . "\t");
   }
   echo("\r");
}
```

P.S. Just so you know, Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a place where we write code for you.  I'm just in the mood to write code :-)

P.P.S. To the real PHP experts here, I'd love to know what optimizations should be made to this code :-)

Answer (score 0):

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) about formatting dates.

```
foreach ($yourarray as $key => $value){
    $yourarray[$key]['date'] = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($value['date']));
}
```

I have assumed you don't mind overwriting the other format.